# Reference to specific FAQ section

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

Is it possible to add a hyperlink to a specific section in the faq, something like this:

```
faq#promotion
```

This way we can inform people, more effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are already there.

Right click on the header section and you'll see that the URL is like this:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask

for example.

In comments just type `[faq#dontask]` to get the link.